# getting segmentation fault on multi dimension array while calculating Levenshtein Distance

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

I was trying to calculate Levenshtein Distance. The following code works for small strings e.g. kit/fit or sitting/knit. But, it gave me a segmentation fault for sunday/saturday strings. After using the GDB(for first time), I figured the problem is with the str2 going beyond the allocated memory space. But I haven't been able to figure out how. I have spent a lot of time on this, now it just seems like I am staring at a wall. Could someone please point out my mistake in the code? Thank You.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


// print array of given size
void print_array( char *s_ptr)
{
  printf("{");
  while(*s_ptr!='\0' && *s_ptr!='\n'){
    printf("%c",*s_ptr++);
  }
  printf("}\n");
}

int min(int a, int b, int c){
   int m = a;
   //printf("a=%d\tb=%d\tc=%d\n",a,b,c);
   if (m > b) m=b;
   if (m > c) m=c;
   return m;
}

int leven_dist(char str1[], char str2[]){

   int len1 = strlen(str1), len2 = strlen(str2);
   int dist[len1][len2];
   int i,j,ldist;

   //int *dist = (int *) malloc(len1*len2*sizeof(int));

   for(i=0;i<=len1;i++){
      dist[i][0] = i;
      printf("dist[%d][0]=%d  ",i,dist[i][0]);
   }
   printf("\tlen1=%d\n",len1);

   for(j=0;j<=len2;j++){
      dist[0][j] = j;
      printf("dist[0][%d]=%d  ",j,dist[0][j]);
   }
   printf("\tlen2=%d\n\n",len2);

   for(j=1;j<=len2;j++){
      for(i=1;i<=len1;i++){
        printf("str1[%d]=%c str2[%d]=%c\n",i-1,str1[i-1],j-1,str2[j-1]);
        if(str1[i-1] == str2[j-1]){
           dist[i][j] = dist[i-1][j-1];
        }
        else {
           dist[i][j] = min(dist[i-1][j]+1,dist[i][j-1]+1,dist[i-1][j-1]+1);
        }
        printf("dist[%d][%d]=%d  ",i,j,dist[i][j]);
      }
    printf("\n");
   }

    for(i=0;i<=len1;i++){
       for(j=0;j<=len2;j++){
         printf("%d\t",dist[i][j]);
       }
     printf("\n");
    }
    ldist= dist[len1][len2];
    //free(dist);
    return ldist;
}

int main( void )
{
  char str1[20]="sunday",str2[20]="saturday";
  int ldist=0;

  printf("String1:"); print_array(str1);
  printf("String2:"); print_array(str2);

  //calculate Levenshtein Distance for strings
  ldist = leven_dist(str1,str2);
  printf("Levenshtein Distance is: %d\n",ldist);

return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
String1:{sunday}
String2:{saturday}
dist[0][0]=0  dist[1][0]=1  dist[2][0]=2  dist[3][0]=3  dist[4][0]=4  dist[5][0]=5  dist[6][0]=6    len1=6
dist[0][0]=0  dist[0][1]=1  dist[0][2]=2  dist[0][3]=3  dist[0][4]=4  dist[0][5]=5  dist[0][6]=6  dist[0][7]=7  dist[0][8]=8    len2=8

str1[0]=s str2[0]=s
dist[1][1]=0  str1[1]=u str2[0]=s
dist[2][1]=1  str1[2]=n str2[0]=s
dist[3][1]=2  str1[3]=d str2[0]=s
dist[4][1]=3  str1[4]=a str2[0]=s
dist[5][1]=4  str1[5]=y str2[0]=s
dist[6][1]=5  
str1[0]=s str2[1]=a
dist[1][2]=1  str1[1]=u str2[1]=a
dist[2][2]=1  str1[2]=n str2[1]=a
dist[3][2]=2  str1[3]=d str2[1]=a
dist[4][2]=3  str1[4]=a str2[1]=a
dist[5][2]=3  str1[5]=y str2[1]=a
dist[6][2]=4  
str1[0]=s str2[2]=t
dist[1][3]=2  str1[1]=u str2[2]=t
dist[2][3]=2  str1[2]=n str2[2]=t
dist[3][3]=2  str1[3]=d str2[2]=t
dist[4][3]=3  str1[4]=a str2[2]=t
dist[5][3]=4  str1[5]=y str2[2]=t
dist[6][3]=4  
str1[0]=s str2[3]=u
dist[1][4]=3  str1[1]=u str2[3]=u
dist[2][4]=2  str1[2]=n str2[3]=u
dist[3][4]=3  str1[3]=d str2[3]=u
dist[4][4]=3  str1[4]=a str2[3]=u
dist[5][4]=4  str1[5]=y str2[3]=u
dist[6][4]=5  
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int dist[len1][len2];
// ....
for(i=0;i<=len1;i++){
   dist[i][0] = i;
```

Every where you are doing the same mistake. If array size is `N`, then the accessible indexes are `0 to N-1`.

```
for(i=0; i<len1;i++) // Notice that <= is changed to <
{
```

If array size is `MxN`, then accessible indexes are `0 to M-1` and `0 to N-1`.

Comment: OMG!! thanks Mahesh. I guess I shouldn't work on this too late into the night. This is really stupid mistake.